# What is causing this error? Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP.subcode=0x0

Tags: ios, swift

Please forgive this but I am at the end of my rope. I am getting the above crash in code that was working yesterday. I am trying to pass date via arrays from view1 to view2 and then from view2 to view3. There is no problem getting from V1 to V2 but I crash when I go from V2 to V3. It is the same code with different variables.

Here is how I prepare for sequel from V1 to V2

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDispenseScreenTwo") {
        var DestViewControllerTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! DispenseScreenTwoViewController;
        DestViewControllerTwo.toPassTwo = enteredDataArrayOne as! [String]
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the segue

```
if blankData != 1 {
        enteredDataArrayOne = [enterDate.text, enterSeason.text, enterSport.text, enterDispTo.text]
        self.appIsWorking ()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenTwo", sender: self)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
    blankData = 0
```

Here is how I prepare for segue from V2 to V3 and I get the error on line     `DestViewControllerThree.toPassThree...`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDispenseScreenThree") {
        var DestViewControllerThree = segue.destinationViewController as! DispenseScreenThreeViewController;
        DestViewControllerThree.toPassThree = enteredDataArrayTwo as! [String]
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the segue from V2 to V3

```
if blankData != 1 {
            enteredDataArrayTwo = [toPassTwo, enterPersonnelName.text, enterDrugID.text, enterPackageNumber.text, enterQty.text, enterExpDate.text]
            println(enteredDataArrayTwo)
            self.appIsWorking()
            performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenThree", sender: self)
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }
    blankData = 0
```

The variables `toPassTwo` and `toPassThree` are both defined as such

```
var toPassTwo: [String] = []
var toPassThree: [String] = []
```

where `toPassTwo` is defined on V2 and `toPassThree` is defined on V2.

There are no build errors. I have tried to include everything I could think that is relevant but I certainly may have missed something. Please, please help me get to the bottom of this. Thank you.

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP.subcode=0x0** is the complete message.  Unless there is somewhere else I should be looking.

Comment: There should be more of a textual message along with that part.

Comment: Take a look at your log on debug area.

Comment: Forgive my newbie reply but my log has the data output that I sent to the log with the `println` statement (I removed those lines from my original question as I did not think they would be useful). At the end of that is `(lldb)`. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @rmaddy I think I may understand more about what you are asking for. In the left side pane if I click on the error is says: `DispenseScreenTwoViewController.prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue, sender : AnyObject!) -> ()` Does that help you?